# What happens to the umblical cord inside the mother?

Tags: pregnancy, children

After giving birth to a child, the umblical cord is cut (and stored if they want). The end connected to the child's navel will fell off eventually but what happens to the end inside the mother?

Will it be removed right after birth by doctors or what happens?

Comment: The umbilical cord is connected to the placenta, which is expelled shortly after birth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Labor is typically divided into 3 stages:

- Stage 1: From the onset of contractions (true labor pains) to full dilatation of the cervix (which is about 10 cm) - this takes about 12 to 18 hours
- Stage 2: From full dilatation of cervix to expulsion of fetus - This takes about ~ 30 minutes
- **Stage 3. From expulsion of fetus to expulsion of placenta - this takes about ~ 15 minutes. During the third stage, the umblical cord which is attached to placenta is expelled along with the placenta**. This would be the answer to your question.

[image]
<sub>Source:[Hympath.com](http://www.humpath.com/IMG/jpg_10143_normal_placenta_28w_1.jpg)</sub>